# Get all Records of a table in Dynamo using AWS Service Proxy?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is their a way to get all the Records of a table in DynamoDB using AWS Service Proxy Option ...

My body mapping JSON:

```
 {
    "TableName": "Fund_Performance",
    "IndexName": "fund-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "fund not null" 
}
```

This gives an error and have tried many other but I coudlnt even find a Operator in AWS Documentation for != or <> and if I use => fund <> '' or fund != '' .... It gives a syntax error

What Shall I do to get all records of a table.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the Records from DynamoDB in AWS...

use Scan - Action rather than Query - Action - which I was using it earlier. In case you want to filter results based on where clause then you may use - Query Action - as per the docs. Limitation of Query Action is ... you cannot use != or <> (negation) operators